# Allow cross-domain access to window object to parent iframe (w/o postMessage)

Tags: javascript

I am creating a javascript console extension for [theia-ide](https://theia-ide.org) for use by students who are on computers where devtools are blocked.

The IDE interface is at `my-project.ide.example.com`, while the iframe preview is at `preview.my-project.ide.example.com`. In order to get [this console](https://jsconsole.com) working, I need access to the window object on the iframe. I know `postMessage()` is preferrable for cross-origin iframe communication, but that is not an option for me as I would have to serialize every imaginable type of javascript object and re-construct it on the other end.

Is there any way to loosen the cross-origin restriction to allow access from the opener window at the "parent" domain?

Comment: To be clear, both documents are on the same domain but different sub-domains?

Comment: Yes, they are on the same domain, but the child iframe is a sub-domain of the parent.

Comment: That the answer there is deprecated doesn't makes your question less a duplicate of the other **question**. If there was an other solution, then it should be posted there, to avoid people having to go through 346 different posts to find the up to date answer. (+ I don't think it's been removed from any browser yet)

Comment: @Kaiido Alternative solutions usually involve `postMessage()`, but my use case is unique in that `postMessage()` is not an option, hence why I think my question should not be marked duplicate.

Comment: Did you try the `document.domain` solution? They use it in the [top 1 domain](https://www.naver.com/) in South Korea, I believe they also use it in facebook, so I guess they did check it works (just tried and it does in FF at least). While there was a lot of discussion asking it to be removed, even just for https, they never really could because it's used everywhere.

Comment: I haven't tried it due to an [issue I'm having](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64689972/how-can-i-allow-document-domain-on-a-sandboxed-iframe) with the iframe being sandboxed. If I can figure that out, that's probably what I will go with for now. Having said that, I don't think it's unreasonable to not want to use a deprecated feature.

Comment: Well when you don't want to use the official way...

Comment: Thinking a bit more about your situation, since you are able to disable the dev-tools, I guess you can install extensions on your students' browsers? If so, I think you can have access directly to the browser console output, even across domains (though I'm not an extensions expert myself).

Comment: Dev tools are disabled by school administrators, and they also do not allow extensions. They're fairly locked down, unfortunately.