# How can I allow document.domain on a sandboxed iframe?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a sandboxed iframe defined like so:

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms allow-modals" src="...">
</iframe>
```

When I set `document.domain` inside the iframe, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'domain' property on 'Document': Assignment is forbidden for sandboxed iframes.
```

How can I allow document.domain to be set within the iframe?

Comment: This maybe could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796767/is-it-possible-to-alter-one-frame-from-another-using-javascript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796767/is-it-possible-to-alter-one-frame-from-another-using-javascript

Comment: don't `sandbox` the iframe ... that's the ONLY way. [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/domain#Failures) states that setting document.domain inside a sandboxed iframe will fail - no if's, it just fails - therefore you can't have your cake (sandbox) and eat it (set document.domain) too :p

Comment: Note that since [you are willing to set this document.domain to allow access between the two contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64689766/allow-cross-domain-access-to-window-object-to-parent-iframe-w-o-postmessage), the sandbox is completely useless: The iframe could remove its own sandbox attributes. So as has been said in the previous comment, don't set the sandbox at all if it's really the way you want to go. But in your position, I would reconsider the why I can't use postMessage. Filtering the few non clonable values isn't that hard.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(answering my own question thanks to comments)*

Since you are willing to set the document.domain to allow access between the to contexts, that defeats the purpose of the sandbox altogether. So, there is no point in sandboxing the iframe in the first place.